# VLOOKUP function in LibreOffice to identify and map two values for 1 label

Tags: merge, vlookup, libreoffice-calc

I've been [searching](http://classroom.synonym.com/use-vlookup-matching-data-10893.html) [many](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions) [examples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WoHWWwUN9Uo) of `VLOOKUP`, with application to LibreOffice, what I'd like to do is unify a set of sheets by a common value.

The information on the two sheets is different, and in fact, each value on the one sheet will be repeated twice on the other, as such, we will have it that, in essence the first sheet `Sheet 1` will look more or less like this:

[image]

and the second, `Sheet 2`, looks like this:

[image]

as you can see, for the column `submission #` in the pink sheet, `Sheet 1`, the value of `4` is repeated twice in `Sheet 2`, the purple one, i.e. the first two entries are both characterized by the value `4` in the column `submission #`.

Initially I was thinking that I might but the values, all the values, from the purple sheet, `Sheet 2`, along side the associated `submission #` index of the pink sheet `Sheet 1`, in this way:

[image]

But it could also work that the `submission #` column with the value of `4` from the pink sheet is conjoined twice onto the `Sheet 2`, purple sheet.

As I said, I've been battling with the "Function generator" button located on the dashboard of LibreOffice to no avail.

How to structure such a function?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with two premises here (correct me if I'm wrong):

1. The rows in Sheet2 are sorted by Submission #.
2. There are always 2 entries in Sheet2 to every entry in Sheet1. No more, no less.

If both my premises are true, you can use VLOOKUP to get the first entry and INDIRECT and MATCH to get the second one, like this:

For the first entry (columns H through L of Sheet1)

```
=VLOOKUP($A2; Sheet2.$A$2:$F$5; 2; FALSE())
```

For the second entry (columns M through Q of Sheet1)

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2.B" & (MATCH($A2; Sheet2.$A$2:$A$5; 1) + 1))
```

I believe you already know how VLOOKUP works, so I'll just explain the second formula.

MATCH will give you the row number of the first entry in Sheet2 with the same Submission # as the entry in Sheet1 (in this example, 2). Add one to it and you'll have the row number of the second entry (3).

INDIRECT will give you the contents of the cell whose address you get when you concatenate "Sheet2.B" and 3 (Sheet2.B3).

If you're not familiar with the $ notation, it doesn't affect the formula at all: it's just there to make it easier for you to copy the formula to the other cells. All you have to do is replace "Sheet2.B" with "Sheet2.C", "Sheet2.D" etc as you copy it to the other columns.

Hope this helps!